# 14.04 installation not booting

Tags: 14.04, boot

I did a full installation using 3 different USBs each burned using a different program. The .iso was the current 14.04 on the Ubuntu website. Each of those installations was done using the Erase Disk option. If I take the USB out, the system does not boot. If I leave the USB in, I get the choice of INSTALL or TRY. The ubuntu files are on the disk but the computer just wlll not go there.

Comment: Please check the boot-order defined in the bios of the computer. In the rare (and not very likely case) that it is configured to boot only from CDROM/DVD or USB - it might explain your issue

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, please make sure you reach the screen where the installer says something to this effect.

"Please remove the disk form the drive and reboot, you can continue to work, however any settings will not be saved"

1. Once there, please reboot and press F2 or F8 or other function key to get into the boot menu option.
2. If that does not appear for some reason, please reboot again (power key).
3. Enter into BIOS (usually it should be DEL key)
4. Go to the Settings and locate the Boot Menu.
5. Locate the Harddisk you have installed Ubuntu 14.04 and move it to the top.
6. Now, reboot. you should be able to.

Comment: Did that. No change. Even tried to install using the Something Else option to mount the HDD as root. Nothing.

Comment: What is the error message you got? Also, at the conclusion you will be prompted with the available OS in the harddrive inthe machine and the option to install GRUB loader. Did you did this step? If so, is grub loading during boot?

Comment: When I remove the stick, the screen goes black and prints "media missing:. Does the same thing when the computer is turned off at the reboot, remove the stick, and turn the computer back on. I conclude that the HDD was not mounted as the root even all the files seem to be on the HDD. I do not know how to manually repair the grub.

Comment: @Avdiel It is more likely an issue with Grub only if it shows the OS options (Grub prompt) and then it doesnt boot. Are you Certain that you have changed the "Booot Media" ??